# Make react native expo app public from localhost

Tags: react-native

im trying to make my react native expo app public so i can show it to my college professor ,is there any way i can leave my pc open to be a server and send him a url so he can see my app ?

Thanks .

Comment: Your localhost can only be accessed through your machine. You can upload your expo app to expo go, however and run it from a different device.

Comment: The only thig i see in docs are something like "eas build" which is for play store - app store i think ,is there any other way i can host also my node js server ??

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://medium.com/@jamischarles/easily-share-a-react-native-app-during-development-d40ac27af6ef

Comment: nah more errors...i open a tunel seems working fine but the node server still does not responding